# Pseudo Class Hover won't work in JavaScript ImageSwap

Tags: javascript, css

Experts;

I have a photo retouching portfolio page that has thumbnail images swapping out the main viewer image. The main viewer image is a sprite that has a Before & After section, showing the original image before it was retouched, and after the retouch. The sprite is loaded into the main viewer div as a background image, set up to reposition as the mouse hovers to show the Before and After sections of the sprite.

When the page initially loads, the main viewer behaves as it should, showing the Before & After position shift on hover. But once a new image is loaded into the viewer, by way of a thumbnail selection, the hover action stops working. I've been at it for a couple of hours now and can't resolve the problem.

An example of the main viewr sprite can be seen here:
http://www.triadimedia.com/frame_01.jpg .
All styles & scripts are contained in the page, which is here:
http://www.triadimedia.com/pfolio_photo_retouch.php .

Any help would be hugely appreciated.

Thanks.

Cayce

Comment: have you tried attaching functions to `mouseover` and `mouseout`?

Comment: i think your code is not working because you have done innerHTML i think you should try to set background image of div

Answer (score 0):

Change your thumbs to use this code:

```
<a onclick="javascript:thumb_swap(1);"></a>
<a onclick="javascript:thumb_swap(2);"></a>
```

etc...

Then replace all your current JS functions with this one:

```
function thumb_swap(num) {
    if(num<10) num = "0"+num;
    var el = document.getElementById('viewer');
    var styles = getComputedStyle(el,null);
    var bgurl = styles.backgroundImage;
    bgurl = bgurl.replace(/_[0-9]+\.jpg/,'_'+num+'.jpg');
    document.getElementById('viewer').style.backgroundImage = bgurl;
}
```

Worked for me in a quick test anyway.